# React router 404 page rendering in all pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-dom 5.2.0` and I am trying to build a `404 page` when user accidently sets a wrong or invalid URL.

**Problem**

The 404 page is rendering in each and every route. Not sure what I am missing here.

**router.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Switch, useLocation, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Pages/home";
import SearchProducts from "./Pages/SearchProducts";
import Product from "./Pages/Product";
import Cart from "./Pages/cart";
import Account from "./Pages/account";
import NotFound from './Pages/404'

export default function Routes(props) {
  function _ScrollToTop(props) {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    useEffect(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, [pathname]);
    return props.children;
  }
  const ScrollToTop = withRouter(_ScrollToTop);
  return (
    <Switch>
      <ScrollToTop>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/search" component={SearchProducts} />
        <Route exact path="/product" component={Product} />
        <Route exact path="/cart" component={Cart} />
        <Route exact path="/account" component={Account} />
        <Route component={NotFound}/>
      </ScrollToTop>
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do not create components inside of other components if possible. Your `ScrollToTop` component should be extracted to a separate file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the offical [code example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match) for 404 (no match) page.

You just need to add `path="*"` to your `<Route component={NotFound}/>`

```
<Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
```

As @Yuriy Yakym said, your `<ScrollToTop>` is causing issues too. Make sure to keep your `<Switch>` clean and follow guidelines from the official docs.

**Suggestion:** Try to create  [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) with scroll to top logic. Make sure that `useEffect` is not inside the function, it should be always at the top level... Learn more about it — [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

Comment: Indeed ScrolltoTop is causing issues, I already tried <Route path = * ... /> but it wasnt working due to scroll to top i guess, Thanks

Comment: Yes, nonetheless, create HOC with your scroll to top logic. And please, read **Rules of Hooks**, it's something you should always keep in mind when working with hooks in React. It will save you some debug time ;)